# Resume for long career as successful independent contractor/mfg rep in medical industry

Tags: resume, contractors

I have had a long career as a medical manufacturers' rep and independent contractor under my own corporation. How do I list my accomplishments so hiring managers don't stop when they see I have been with my own company for 20 years? I am looking for opportunities as an employee not just as a contractor. My resume seems so long when I list all the companies I have represented

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there are no alternate answers popping up for this, allow me to elaborate on my comment.

Rather than list every single project under one company list the few most relevant to the job you are applying for.

For example you may wish to list the 3 or 4 most recent projects that you found challenging or where you learnt something new.

You may wish to pick the 3 or 4 which show you have a diverse knowledge of many subjects, for example you might choose to list one where you had to use one technology to do one thing and a completely different technology for another. This shows you have a diverse and useful skill set

You might wish to be specific, and instead choose to list the 3 or 4 that most accurately show your knowledge in a certain skill set, for example a particular technology that you used frequently, and wish to keep using.

You might choose to eliminate the ones that were just menial, day to day tasks that dont show off what you are capable of.

Remember the point of your CV is to show off what you can do, in a short and concise manner, you want to show the recruiter you know your stuff, but you dont want them to get bored with an overly long 'previous projects' section.

Keep it short, keep it sweet, keep it relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Just mention your accomplishments first without giving much focus on the firm and may be later  you can give out the company info during interview.

Comment: as far as I can tell, this answer violates "back it up" rule from the [FAQ]: **"answers should be backed up either with a reference, or experiences that happened to you personally. You should always include in your answer information about why you think your answer is correct."**
I think the post would better be [edit]ed to include required details, which would help encourage more upvotes, give readers more confidence about the answer, and discourage downvotes / delete flags